# Haxe: Binding pattern with abstract fields access methods

Tags: data-binding, operator-overloading, abstract, haxe

I'd like to make wrapper to implement simple data binding pattern -- while some data have been modified all registered handlers are got notified. I have started with this (for js target):

```
class Main {
    public static function main() {
        var target = new Some();
        var binding = new Bindable(target);
        binding.one = 5;
        // binding.two = 0.12; // intentionally unset field
        binding.three = []; // wrong type
        binding.four = 'str'; // no such field in wrapped class
        trace(binding.one, binding.two, binding.three, binding.four, binding.five);
        // outputs: 5, null, [], str, null
        trace(target.one, target.two, target.three);
        // outputs: 5, null, []
    }
}

class Some {
    public var one:Int;
    public var two:Float;
    public var three:Bool;
    public function new() {}
}

abstract Bindable<TClass>(TClass) {
    public inline function new(source) { this = source; }
    @:op(a.b) public function setField<T>(name:String, value:T) {
        Reflect.setField(this, name, value);
        // TODO notify handlers
        return value;
    }
    @:op(a.b) public function getField<T>(name:String):T {
        return cast Reflect.field(this, name);
    }
}
```

So I have some frustrating issues: interface of wrapped object doesn't expose to wrapper, so there's no auto completion or strict type checking, some necessary attributes can be easily omitted or even misspelled.

Is it possible to fix my solution or should I better move to the macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost suggested here to open an issue regarding this problem. Because some time ago, there was a @:followWithAbstracts meta available for abstracts, which could be (or maybe was?) used to forward fields and call @:op(a.b) at the same time. But that's not really necessary, Haxe is powerful enough already.

```
abstract Binding<TClass>(TClass) {
    public function new(source:TClass) { this = source; }
    @:op(a.b) public function setField<T>(name:String, value:T) {
        Reflect.setField(this, name, value);
        // TODO notify handlers
        trace("set: $name -> $value");
        return value;
    }
    @:op(a.b) public function getField<T>(name:String):T {
        trace("get: $name");
        return cast Reflect.field(this, name);
    }
}

@:forward
@:multiType
abstract Bindable<TClass>(TClass) {
    public function new(source:TClass);
    @:to function to(t:TClass) return new Binding(t);
}
```

We use here multiType abstract to forward fields, but resolved type is actually regular abstract. In effect, you have completion working and @:op(a.b) called at the same time.

Comment: Very neat solution. It still allows abuse of setting/getting absent fields and wrong type assigns, but auto completion works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need @:forward meta on your abstract. However, this will not make auto-completion working unless you remove @:op(A.B) because it shadows forwarded fields.

EDIT: it seems that shadowing happened first time I added @:forward to your abstract, afterwards auto-completion worked just fine.

Comment: I don't think forwarding really helps in this case, he wants to execute some logic when a field is set (the "notify handlers" comment). `@:op(a.b)` is only used as a "fallback" for fields that don't exist on the abstract.

Comment: Forwarding really won't help. All forwarded fields are excluded from the overloaded operators. Moreover I can't create as many abstract wrappers as I have different data models.